# JQuery + Fullcalendar - large number of iteration with jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to render large number of events (about 50, and it's might be more).

```
                    for (var eventIndex = 0; eventIndex < resp.select_events.length; eventIndex++){
                    var event = resp.select_events[eventIndex];
                    c.fullCalendar('renderEvent',{
                        id: event.id,
                        title: eventName,
                        start: event.event_date,
                        description: eventDesc,
                        write: event.write
                    },true);
                }
```

It takes several seconds, and sometimes browser asks me for abort scipt execution. So, I think, I need a way to do it somehow like async - parrallel with execution of last part of script. Can you advice some tool or something like that? Thx

Comment: Do you have to render one by one? Why dont you setup first an array like a JSON array and add it to eventSources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have to render one by one? Why dont you setup first an array like a JSON array and add it to eventSources? The best way for your calendar to render large number of events is to let Fullcalendar do the job for you. You are trying ,in my perspective ofc, do what fullcalendar internally already does. Check the example below and this is if you have to do this client side, i would do this server side.

```
          var jsonarray = [];    
          for (var eventIndex = 0; eventIndex < resp.select_events.length; eventIndex++){

               /* c.fullCalendar('renderEvent',{
                    id: event.id,
                    title: eventName,
                    start: event.event_date,
                    description: eventDesc,
                    write: event.write
                },true);*/
               var event = resp.select_events[eventIndex];
               var myevent = {
                    "id": event.id,
                    "title": eventName,
                    "start": event.event_date,
                    "description": eventDesc,
                    "write": event.write
               }; 
               jsonarray.push(myevent); 
            }

            c.fullCalendar('addEventSource', jsonarray);
```

Let em know if you have any doubt

Comment: thx, i'm just now find that way) I have no idea, that this way much faster) I think developer should mention that in documentation)

Comment: I think he mention's something...glad i could help. Btw you should do this process server side and not client side, just pass the already constructed json array from server to client and you will just do the addEventSource thing in client side, because you dont know the processing capacity of every user computer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the loop itself may help at some degree. Read this article http://jsperf.com/fastest-array-loops-in-javascript/11

Also this https://blogs.oracle.com/greimer/entry/best_way_to_code_a

In general fastest way for your loop is `while` loop in reverse, with simplified the test condition:

```
var i = arr.length; while (i--) {/*....*/}
```